# Order Id does not exist but payment is received

Tags: magento

On my live website customer paid via `Amazon Pay` and order id# was assigned in Magento admin but customer's payment was also done by Authorized.net, this is quite strange. 
How this happened

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is same **orderId** is existing on two places, **Authorized.net and Amazon Pay**